# Generalizing Fano's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Fano's inequality says the following:

> Theorem: Let $X$ be a random variable with range $M$. Let $\hat{X} = g(Y)$ be the predicted value of $X$ given some transmitted value $Y$, where $g$ is a deterministic function. Let $p_e$ be the probability of making a mistake, i.e., $p_e = Pr[ \hat{X} \ne X ]$. Then $p_e \ge \frac{H(X\mid Y) - 1}{\log|M|}$.

It seems to me that Fano's inequality is useful when $X$ is the output of an algorithm computing some function, i.e., for any fixed input there is a *unique* correct output.

I'm interested in the following generalization: Suppose $X$ is the output of an algorithm for a problem, where, for a given input, there are *multiple* valid solutions. In other words, for each input $I$, there is a fixed subset $S_I$ of values that are correct, i.e., if $\hat{X} \in S_I$ we succeed (instead of just $\hat{X} = X$). For instance, $X$ could be a maximal independent set of a given input graph $I$, and $S_I$ would be the set of all MISs.

How would I bound the error probability of guessing an element in $S_I$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51892/5038.  lease [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.